# Angular reactive form doesn't gets reset onSubmit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

[image: **enter image description here**]

whenever I entered some values and submits this resets form but doesn't remove any validation errors

I have tried many things on StackOverflow but nothing solved the error

I have tried different kind of things for hours and still no luck finally now I'm asking the question but stack overflow says my question is mostly code add some text so I'm writing some long text this is not much to read so please read the code and help me thank you

here's the ts code

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {ItemCategory} from "../../models/item.model";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {AuthService} from "../../auth/auth.service";
import {mimeType} from "../validators/mime-type.validator";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-item',
  templateUrl: './create-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-item.component.css']
})
export class CreateItemComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading = false;
  form: FormGroup;
  imagePreview: string;
  categories = Object.keys(ItemCategory).map(key => ItemCategory[key])
  private authStatusSub: Subscription;


  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authStatusSub = this.authService
      .authStatusListener
      .subscribe(authStatus => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
    this.loadForm();
  }

  onSavePost() {
    this.form.reset()
  }

  loadForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]}),
      category: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      description: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]),
      image: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required], mimeType)
    });
  }

  onImagePicked(event: Event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.form.patchValue({image: file});
    this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imagePreview = reader.result as string;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

here's the HTML

```
    <h1>Create Item</h1>
<div class="container">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSavePost()" *ngIf="!isLoading">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="title" placeholder="Item Title">
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('title').invalid">Please enter a valid item title</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="category">
          <mat-option [value]="null" disabled>Choose Category</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">
            {{category}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('category').invalid">Please enter a valid item title</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput rows="4" formControlName="description" placeholder="Item Description"></textarea>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('description').invalid">Please enter a suitable Description.</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <div>
        <button mat-stroked-button type="button" (click)="filePicker.click()">Pick Main Image</button>
        <input type="file" #filePicker (change)="onImagePicked($event)">
      </div>

      <div class="image-preview" *ngIf="imagePreview !== '' && imagePreview && form.get('image').valid">
        <img [src]="imagePreview" [alt]="form.value.title">
      </div>

      <button id="create-button" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Create</button>

    </form>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: if mat-error is in mat-form-field, there is no need for your *ngIf.  I think you can remove  form.get('xyz').invalid.  If mat-error tag is outside, then you need a *ngIf.

Comment: try this:https://therichpost.com/angular-9-how-to-reset-form-after-submit/

Comment: @Marc it works without *ngIf thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the fix

html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #formDirective="ngForm (submit)="onCreateItem(formDirective)" *ngIf="!isLoading" >
```

typescript

```
onCreateItem(formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {

    formDirective.resetForm();
    this.form.reset();

  }
```

Comment: this is an issue with angular material library

Answer (score 1):

instead of reset you can explicit set errors (to null).

see:  [setErrors](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors)

```
this.form.setErrors(null, {emitEvent: true});
```

Or you can try:

```
this.form.reset({onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `formGroup.reset()`, the `reset()` method will be called for all the `formGroup`'s **descendants**.

A `FormGroup` might contain several `FormControl`s.

Here is what happens on `FormControl.reset()`:

```js
  reset(formState: any = null, options: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean} = {}): void {
    this._applyFormState(formState);
    this.markAsPristine(options);
    this.markAsUntouched(options);
    this.setValue(this.value, options);
    this._pendingChange = false;
  }
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1139-L1145).

After `this.setValue(this.value, options);`, `AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity()` will be called, which will **invoke the validators**:

```js
(this as {errors: ValidationErrors | null}).errors = this._runValidator();
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L650)

So, that's why you're still seeing the errors.

What you can do is to add some conditions:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('category').invalid && form.get('category').pristine">Please enter a valid item title</mat-error>
```

The `pristine` state indicates that the control did not have any changes(note that it's different from `touched`).

Comment: I tried this, my friend, it doesn't work since I'm using angular material I don't even need to use *ngIf="form.get('description').invalid" (I found this out now in the comments)  its all handled by the material library so I think somethings wrong there anyway thank you great explanation on how form reset works

Answer (score 1):

You can add `#ngForm` to the `form` attribute and then show errors after when the form is submitted. On resetting your form for `form:FormGroup`, you would see no errors then.

Here is simple example:

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSavePost()" *ngIf="!isLoading" #_form="ngForm">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="title" placeholder="Item Title">
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('title').invalid && _form.submitted">Please enter a valid item title</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

See above code. I have added `_form.submitted` along with your `title:FormControl` validity. This simply means. The error text or `<mat-error>...</mat-error>` would only be visible if the form is submitted.